# REST API GET users

Tags: rest-api, users

when I do http://dayroomstay.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users

I get:

```
 "code": "rest_user_cannot_view",
    "message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to list users.",
    "data": {
        "status": 401
    }
```

I am using Postman...
please help

Comment: How have you configured auth with Postman? That's an authenticated endpoint, I get the same result if I visit that endpoint ( I'm a logged out user so it's expected )

Comment: Hi Tom, thank you,

Comment: could you direct me in the right directions as to how configure Auth with postman? I am new to it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/): you need to add a Header named `X-WP-Nonce` to your requests to the API that require authentication, as you can see in the jQuery example.

However the catch is getting that nonce in the first place. WordPress inject that token itself in the post editing screens. Type `wpApiSettings` in the developer console and you can get the nonce. You will need to send your `wordpress_logged_in` cookie too, that can be retrieved from the request headers in the Network tab of your browser dev tools.

I'm sharing an example of how you put that headers in your Postman request:

[image: Postman example of Authenticated request to WordPress REST API]

However making it for an app that is not coupled to the WP backend itself can be cumbersome, that´s why there are other options, like Basic authentication that I´m not a big fan, and JWT authentication plugin. Both are linked in the documentation page that I linked.

Comment: worked! @JesusFranco You're a genius

Comment: Glad to be of help. Remember your next questions sharing the code that have you written, or in cases too complex, a minimal reproducible example, that would help the community helping you more quickly.

Comment: Now I am wondering how to generate the nonce and the cookies using only the code.

Comment: Look at the docs page it is linked, the very first code it is what you'd need to put into the controller/script/whatever you are using to send the credentials to your alternative client.